# VisualStudio 2010 MyProjectName.application file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When i build my project VisualStudio creates allso a file names MyProjectName.application. What is this file used for? How can i disable the creation of this file in VisualStudio?

Using VisualStudio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older versions of visual studio (<2010) you would deploy your application using Setup Wizard but ClickOnce is newer and preferred way of deployment. For ClickOnce deployment model ***.application*** files are default deployment manifest for your application i.e they have all the information regarding the choices you make when you deploy your application using ClickOnce. You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699352.aspx) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/deploying-windows-applications-using-visual-studio-2010/)

To disable ClickOnce, open your project's properties and do following:

1. Under **Signing tab**, uncheck "*Sign the ClickOnce manifests*".
2. Under **Security tab**, uncheck "*Enable ClickOnce security settings*".

after that delete .application file and it should not reappear.

Answer (score 0):

.application files are default deployment manifest for ClickOnce applications.